# Removing elements from list and importing list into another code

Tags: python

I'm trying to list all the html files in a single directory which works fine. However I'm trying to remove everything that is not a html file from that list as well.

i have 8 files called 1, 2, 3... etc. and 6.htmxl (remove) and pipe.sh.save(remove)

The code I made removes the .htmxl file but does not remove the .sh.save file from the list.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pyimport
import time


def main():
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('/home/pi/keyboard/html') if isfile(join('/home/pi/keyboard/html',f)) ]
    j = 0
    print len(onlyfiles)

    for i in onlyfiles:

            if i.find(".html") == -1:
                    print i
                    print  "not a html"
                    j = onlyfiles.index(i)
                    print j
                    del onlyfiles[j]
            else:
                    print i
                    print "html found"

            time.sleep(0.5)

    outfiles = onlyfiles
    print outfiles
    return outfiles

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I also have another code which is suppose to get the "outfiles" list

```
import server_handler

files = server_handler.main()

fileList = server_handler.outfiles
```

But when I run it I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'outfiles'
```

I'm running nearly the exact same code on another code which is creating 'output' and I import it in the exact same way so I'm not sure why its not importing correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `i.find(".html")` with `i.endswith(".html")`. Now you should get only HTML files (or more precisely only files that look like HTML).

For the second part - remove:

```
fileList = server_handler.outfiles
```

`server_handler.main()` already returns the list so you have it in `files`. The last line doesn't make any sense.

**EDIT:**

[Martin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32313631/3936732) answer has better way to get files. So I recommend you use his advice and not mine :).

Comment: thanks. im pretty new to functions in python so i have a lot of trouble understanding them. As far as the i.endswith(). its working but still have same problem with pipe.sh.save being in the list.

Comment: @AceScottie That's weird (that the _pipe.sh.save_ is still there). You should probably use [Martin's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32313631/3936732) answer, I think it's better.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the following approach more suitable, it uses Python's [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob) module:

```
import glob

print glob.glob('/home/pi/keyboard/html/*.html')
```

This will return you a list of all files in that folder ending in `.html` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This would work if main was a class, and you used

```
   class main():
     def __init__(self):
        ....
        self.outfiles = onlyfiles
        return self.outfiles
```